# Enviar información en variables por el método POST con Ajax [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando JavaScript (jQuery), y necesito enviar ciertos datos almacenados en variables a un archivo .php en segundo plano, sin que el usuario tenga que rellenar ningún formulario y sin pulsar ningún botón.

### Solución:

```
var datos = {
    "variable1" : variable1, // Dato #1 a enviar
    "variable2" : variable2 // Dato #2 a enviar
    // etc...
};

var url = "/ejemploArchivo.php"; // URL a la cual enviar los datos

enviarDatos(datos, url); // Ejecutar cuando se quiera enviar los datos

function enviarDatos(datos, url){
    $.ajax({
            data: datos,
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            success:  function (response) {
                console.log(response); // Imprimir respuesta del archivo
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error); // Imprimir respuesta de error
            }
    });
}
```

Los datos de la variable `datos`, serán recibidos por el archivo de la `url` indicada en la variable global `$_POST`. Ejemplos `$_POST['variable1']`, `$_POST['variable2']`

Comment: sabias que jQuery es una libreria hecha en JavaScript?, puedes agregar el ejemplo de lo que intentastes

Comment: @JackNavaRow Sí lo sé, no he intentado nada más que crear un formulario invisible y enviarlo con jQuery en vez de botón, pero ahora ya no me sirve porque tengo muchos datos y quisiera saber si hay otro método. Gracias por responder

Comment: No logro entender le contexto de tu problema, eso de formulario invisible no me queda claro, lo que si tengo claro es que para enviar datos por POST con jQuery tienes la función `$.ajax({})` y su abreviado `$.post()` que te permitiría enviar tu variables sin la necesidad de un formulario.

Comment: Ajax tiene un parámetro `data` el cual conocerás si has trabajado con formularios. Puedes construir un objeto con los pares clave/valor y pasarlos en ese parámetro `data`. Por ejemplo: `var datos={nombre: 'Pedro', edad:'30'};` y luego en la petición Ajax: `data: datos`  ... eso enviaría la info exactamente igual que si fuera un formulario. Está claro que los valores pueden ser tomados de elementos HTML u otros por los métodos ya conocidos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por ejemplo teniendo un botón que al presionar enviará los datos de tus variables a una segunda página que procesará los datos tendriamos algo así.

***Html***

```
<input type="button" value="Guardar" id="btn_save">
```

***Javascript***

```
var var_1 = 'a',
  var_2 = 'b',
  var_3 = 'c',
  var_4 = 'd';

$(function() {

      $('#btn_save').on('click', function() {

          $.post('procesarDatos.php', {
              "var_1": var_1,
              "var_2": var_2,
              "var_3": var_3,
              "var_4": var_4
            },function(data) {
              console.log('procesamiento finalizado', data);
          });
      })

})
```

***procesarDatos.php***

```
<?
// con esto passa a las variables PHP los datos de las variables pasadas por
// post, luego que hagas funcionar tu script debes preocuparte de la seguridad
// de los datos que estás recibiendo en estas variables
$var_1 = $_POST["var_1"];
$var_2 = $_POST["var_2"];
$var_3 = $_POST["var_3"];
$var_4 = $_POST["var_4"];
```

---

La documentación de jQuery te entrega todos los detalles necesarios para que puedas modificar el código a tu conveniencia.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Para temas de seguridad hay mucho en internet pero puedes empezar por lo básico con este post
https://www.imaginanet.com/blog/seguridad-en-php-basica-escribiendo-aplicaciones-web-seguras.html

Comment: Vale, gracias. Pero no encuentro como usar esos datos (`var_1`, etc) en el archivo `procesarDatos.php`, ¿Podrías editarlo y añadir un simple ejemplo?

Comment: Listo! modifiqué mi respuesta agregando temas de seguridad para que complementes.

Comment: @nerdcoder si bien tu pregunta ayudo al OP , [trata de responder preguntas bien formadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)